# I need help creating an explicit inner join, for my coursework

Tags: sqlite, ms-access-2010, vb.net-2010

I have a Microsoft Access 2010 database, which includes the Bookings and Customer tables. The primary table is the Bookings table. The Customer table is linked to the Bookings table through its customer ID, which is a foreign key in the Bookings table. I want to retrieve the email address of the customer that is linked to a certain booking. However, a syntax error message keeps appearing and I can't tell where the error is in the SQL.

This is for my computer science coursework. I need to make a hotel room booking system. I am trying to send automated reminder emails to the customer, a week before they are due to arrive for their booking. I'm programming it in VB.Net 2010 express and have a Microsoft Access 2010 database set up for it.

- I've checked over all of the names of the tables and columns multiple times, but none of them are incorrectly spelled.
- I've gone through the Khan Academy tutorials on the joins and used the SQLite  interface to test my query. It works there, but not in my system.

Here is my code:

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb

Dim CN As OleDbConnection
Dim DR As OleDbDataReader
Dim SQL As String

Sub OpenDatabase()
    CN = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\Coursework Prototype Database.mdb;")
    CN.Open()
End Sub

Public Sub ExecuteSQL()
    Dim CM As New OleDbCommand(SQL, CN)
    DR = CM.ExecuteReader
End Sub

Sub RetrieveCustomerEmail()
    OpenDatabase()
    SQL = ("SELECT tblCustomer.Email_Address FROM tblBookings JOIN tblCustomer ON tblBookings.CustomerID = tblCustomer.CustomerID Where tblBookings.BookingID = 1")
    ExecuteSQL()
    DR.Read()

    Dim CustomerEmail As String = DR.Item("Email_Address").ToString
    CN.Close()
End Sub
```

I expected the result to be an email address, but instead I just got a syntax error message saying

> Syntax error in FROM clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MS Access requires that inner joins be explicitly stated as [`INNER JOIN`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/inner-join-operation-b9e73ab6-884a-403e-9f22-cb502feae36a), and will not interpret the `JOIN` shorthand for an inner join as accepted by other RDBMS.

As such, your SQL statement will need to be:

```sql
SELECT tblCustomer.Email_Address 
FROM tblBookings INNER JOIN tblCustomer ON tblBookings.CustomerID = tblCustomer.CustomerID
WHERE tblBookings.BookingID = 1
```